# How can I create a text based game like Zork in PHP?

Tags: php, text-based

I'm interested in creating a text-based game similar to [Zork](http://thcnet.net/error/index.php). The source code doesn't give away much, it's clear that the text input is submitted by php using the post method and the page is reloaded.

Where should I start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those text adventure games are based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-machine

PHP probably just serves as access channel to the game runtime, maybe using a pipe.